# Align image to left, middle and right without using float

Tags: html, css

Is possible align three image in the same line to left, middle and right without using `float` but only `text-align`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way of doing this using `text-align: justify` and it works as follows:

Suppose that you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/100">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/100">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/100">
    <span class="filler"></span>
</div>
```

Apply the following CSS:

```css
.wrap {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 100px; /* option if you need tighter wrap of the border or background color */
}
.wrap img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.filler {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The `.filler` element needs to use `display: inline-block` and is given a width of 100%.  This causes the other inline elements (images) to be distributed evenly across the width of the parent element.

Sometimes, you may see an extra white space below the bottom edge of the line box containing the images but you can get rid of it by setting the font size to 0px and vertical-align to top.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AnYxC/

**Note:**
Some people prefer to use a pseudo-element to add the filler element.  However, if you don't mind the extra markup, my example works fine.

Comment: See comment about getting rid of bottom hanging white space due to the filler element.  Some people use a pseudo-element to add the filler but only when extra markup is frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 divs, with equal width, then place each image in their own div, and you can align them how you want in that.

```
   <div id="container">
   <div id="left"><img src="image1.png" /></div>
   <div id="center"><img src="image2.png" /></div>
   <div id="right"><img src="image3.png" /></div>

   #left,#right,#center {width:300px;}
   #left{text-align:left;float:left;}
   #center {text-align:center;float:left;}
   #right {text-align:right;float:left;}
```

You have to float the divs, but you are still using text-align for the images.